# Vuetify - How do I open/activate v-select menu from developer tools console?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vue 3.1 project using Vuetify 3.4.5 package. We recently updated from Vue 2.1.

We have run into an issue with our automated testing involving the v-select elements. We are unable to "click" the select element and open the option menu to select one of the options.  With the older version of vuetify, document.getElementById('v-select-id').click() would open the menu and allow us to select an option. After the update, the same .click() command only puts the element in focus without opening the menu.

I can test this with the demo provided by Vuetify and calling .click() on the input inside the select

https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVj9EKgjAUhl9lnBtvSokKSkwIoR6goAv1YulJBnMbc0kRvXvbzKS773zncPj//AWdrqK9UmF/R4ghMdgqTg2mhSAk6edUKY9+qKQwlAnUX+VlhxwrMwpCOL0i3xVwGjxMm5jZ751d5UFGObtJLRgNZiTIJJea1tLxwSKrvT6i1M1wccYH7RxcnrJlognK6XGaRGOKMaoV/1mdGaok0a8ivGewDFfhYgsO1uEGyg9bcFKZ

So my question is which element do we actually need to click on to trigger the options to display.

I have tried each element under the v-select div to trigger the menu but each one only puts the item in focus without triggering it.